# How to change terminal command color linux

Tags: linux, terminal, elementaryos, terminal-emulator

I am using Elementary 6 Odin, and I am trying to make commands like “sudo” red and “apt” green, any help would be appreciated!

My .bashrc file: https://pastebin.com/5mF6vnDj

edit: I mean something like this:

~$ red(sudo) green(apt) white(…)

Comment: have a look in ~/.bashrc

Comment: @Bolli What do you mean ? I do understand a bit of bash, but not enough to understand that file.

Answer (score 0):

Open `~/.bashrc` in text editor and uncomment the line:

```
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

to be:

```
force_color_prompt=yes
```

save and close the file - then run this command: `source ~/.bashrc`
Or simply close the Terminal and open a new one.

If you want to choose your own colors, you wil need to read up on it https://www.howtogeek.com/307701/how-to-customize-and-colorize-your-bash-prompt/ or somewhere else :)

Comment: Thanks !, I've done that as seen in my .bashrc file it doesn't work, still thanks for the answer tho